# Как сделать SOAP сервис на spring boot, если генерируется несколько XSD схем?

Tags: spring-boot, soap

В примере в https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ используется xsd схема, единая для запроса и ответа.

У меня нет готовой xsd схемы, есть только пример запроса и ответа. Пробую генерировать xsd схему (в том числе с помощью онлайн-сервисов). Из одного только запроса получается несколько xsd (и с ответом также). Как работать в этом случае?

Есть ли где-нибудь пример проекта, где как запрос, так и ответ, формируются из нескольких xsd схем? Какова последовательность создания такого сервиса?

Или может быть есть простые примеры подобного на других языках (python?) или инструментах?